# reload a page onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple log on page here: www.mrpbennett.com. I am looking to refresh the page so it removes my password and user name. I currently have the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-signin" type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="login">login</button>
```

```js
function check(form) { 
    if (form.userid.value == "admin" && form.pswrd.value == "123qwe!!") {
        window.open('http://www.mrpbennett.com/mysite')
    }
    else {
        alert("Error Password or Username")
    }
}
```

This is a super super simple bit of JS but is there anything I can do here to make the page refresh after I have clicked log on? Also is there a way to make the log on button work on pressing enter as well as clicking in?

Comment: Why refresh the page? Couldn't you just clear the values of the input fields? Also note that the log on script you have there is literally the most unsecure thing imaginable.

Comment: You do know that anyone can view the source of your page and see the username and password?

Comment: problems spotted after first read: 1) password plain, 2) hardcoded credentials, 3) client side check, 4) not authing anything, but just hiding a link, 5) abusing window.open. please don't do things this way.

Comment: that is totally what i thought, this is a snippet i took from a tutorial. My JS skills arent that great. so any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You should try `form.reset()` instead. It clears all elements in the target form.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Answer (score 0):

USE

`window.location.reload();`

But, is much better  clear the values